# Segmentation fault with multithreaded array

Tags: c, linux, segmentation-fault, debian

I am trying to make multithread array sorting program in c. But when I run the program, I get an "segmentation fault" error. 
Can someone help?
What should I change? First array should be 300 the other should be 500. We sort sequences separately first. After that merge 2 sorted sequences. I use "gcc -pthreads -0 soru1 soru1.c" and "./soru1" commands.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#define size 800

int orginal_dizi[size], dizi1[300], dizi2[500], dizi3[size];
int sayi,a=1;

int boyutbul(int *the)
{
    int number=-1;
    while(the[++number]!='\0'){}
    return number;
}

void*runner(void *param)
{
    int temp,i,k;
    int *bolum = param;
    sayi = boyutbul(bolum);
    printf("\n----------unsorted %d. array-----------\n\n",a);
    for(i=0; i<sayi;i++)
    printf("%d\n", bolum[i]);

    for(i=0; i<sayi;i++)
    {
        for(k=0; k<(sayi-i-1);k++)
        {
            if(bolum[k]>bolum[k+1])
            {
                temp=bolum[k];
                bolum[k]=bolum[k+1];
                bolum[k+1]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("\n----------sorted %d. array-----------\n\n",a);
    for(i=0; i<sayi;i++)
    printf("%d\n", bolum[i]);
    a++;
    pthread_exit(0);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_t tid1,tid2, tid3;
    int i=0;
    while(i<size)
    {
        int yenisayi=1+rand()%1500;
        int aynimi=0, j=0;
        while(j<i)
        {
            if(orginal_dizi[j]==yenisayi)
            {
                aynimi=1;
                break;
            }
        j++;
        }
        if(aynimi)
        continue;
        orginal_dizi[i]=yenisayi;
        i++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        if(i<(300))
        {
            dizi1[i]=orginal_dizi[i];
        }
        else
        {
            dizi2[i-(500)-1]= orginal_dizi[i];
        }
    }
    pthread_create(&tid1,NULL,runner,(void *)dizi1);
    pthread_join(tid1,NULL);

    pthread_create(&tid2,NULL,runner,(void *)dizi2);
    pthread_join(tid2,NULL);

    for(i=0; i<size;i++)
    {
        if(i<300)
        {
            dizi3[i]=dizi1[i];
        }
        else
        {
            dizi3[i]=dizi2[i-500];
        }
    }

    pthread_create(&tid3,NULL,runner,(void *)dizi3);
    pthread_join(tid3,NULL);

    FILE *fp;
    if((fp=fopen("son.txt","w"))== NULL)
    printf("Dosya acilamadi.");

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        fprintf(fp, "%d\n", dizi3[i]);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn how to debug it. Multithreading is not simple, and if you are up to it you will need this skill.

Answer (score 1):

There is no multithreading in this program: every thread is immediately joined; noting runs in parallel.

The real problem is in `boyutbul`, which tries to figure out the length of the array by looking for `'\0'`. The way you initialize the arrays, there is no guarantee that they would have the terminating 0 (in fact, they wouldn't have any zeroes), so the program is doomed to access them beyond the bounds. This is UB.